# How to create a plot a new DataFrame based on another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

So I have this type of dataframe:

```
     Time  Type
1      81  sell
4       9  sell
7      36  sell
10     82   buy
13    106   buy
..    ...   ...
722   105  sell
723   105  sell
727   110  sell
728   110  sell
729   110  sell
```

Where Time shows the hour of the week and Type shows the action (buy or sell). I would like to plot a chart were X is the hours of the week from 1-140, and Y to be the count of buys and sells during the time, on a multi-bar chart. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly,

```
df.groupby(['Time']).apply(lambda x: x['Type'].value_counts()).plot(kind='bar')
```

or if you want bars next to each other.

```
df = df.groupby(['Time']).apply(lambda x: x['Type'].value_counts())
df.reset_index().pivot('Time','level_1','Type').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error:
TypeError: no numeric data to plot

When I try df.groupby(['Time', 'Type']).count()  I get a list of tuples like: 

Index: [(0, sell), (2, buy), (4, buy), (5, buy)....]

Comment: a list of tuples?

Comment: When I type  df = df.groupby(['Time','Type']).count()  and when I print it I get this https://prnt.sc/rxr3na

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rxra4p I've gotten to this point. Now, how do I plot this so I get X=Time and Y=Buys,Sells ?

Comment: I don't get what level_1 stands for? And how do I change that variable because when I change it I get an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211499/discussion-between-jwillis0720-and-blennd).

Answer (score 0):

Using my method I created two new columns for the count of sell and buy and then grouped by Time and Type. Then I created a plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1=df.copy()
df1['Type_Count_Sell'] = np.where(df1['Type'] == 'sell', 1, 0)
df1['Type_Count_Buy'] = np.where(df1['Type'] == 'buy', 1, 0)
df1=df1.groupby(['Time', 'Type']).sum().reset_index()
#df1=df1.loc[df1.Time != '...']
df1['Time']=df1['Time'].astype(int)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Buys an dSells Count')
ax.set_xlabel('Hour')
ax.set_ylabel('Count of Type')
ax.bar(df1['Time'], df1['Type_Count_Sell'], width=1, color='b', align='center')
ax.bar(df1['Time']+1, df1['Type_Count_Buy'], width=1, color='g', align='center')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works. But for some reason it plots the same number of buys and sells, which is not the case in my dataframe. Any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: @blennd I updated my answer with the edit "changed groupby to sum instead of count, which was an error." I also increased the width of the bar from 0.2 to 1.